# Does comment style affect binary size?

Tags: c, comments, atmega, eeprom

I am getting started to the embedded system's world. During this journey I came across to a "different" way to comment functions:

```
ISR(INT0_vect) {         /* Run every time there is a change on button*/
```

I particularly prefer something like:

```
// Run every time there is a change on button
ISR(INT0_vect) {
```

Is it just a "taste thing" or by commenting like that I can "save" some EEPROM space in my ATMEGA168A?

Comment: This will be highly opinion based.

Comment: I disagree unless the compiler treats it equally

Comment: Comments are stripped by the preprocessor. So the "*compiler*" never cares about them because they never reach the compiler.

Comment: Unless your *source code* is being stored in the EEPROM, style of commenting doesn't matter; comments are not preserved in the generated machine code in any form.

Comment: I wish you have said it in your first comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style of comments is purely an aesthetic concern.  Compilers disregard all comments in your code when generating an object file, so how you format comments will have no bearing on EEPROM space.